# RewriteRule giving a server error when write .com

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with the following Rules. The following rules working like

`www.address.com/profile/username` but when i write after the username (**.com**) like this

`www.address.com/profile/username.com` then i am getting internal server error. How can i fix this problem anyone can help me here please ?

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^profile/(followers|friends|saved)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?username=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: How should `www.address.com/profile/username.com` be rewritten to ?

Comment: @anubhava Do you mean it is not rewritten problem ?

Comment: No I am just asking how should it be handled as per your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make your regex more open like these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]  
RewriteRule ^profile/(followers|friends|saved)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`[^/]` matches any character that is not `/`